# problema votación python

Tags: python, array, lista, ordenamiento

Estoy practicando en python pero no soy capaz de resolver el siguiente apartado:

simular la fase de votación de un concurso tipo Eurovisión.Supondremos
que hay 10 participantes (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J).
Cada participante otorgará 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, y 1 puntos a otros participantes (no puede
votarse a sí mismo y tiene que conceder todos los puntos y no puede votar más de una vez
a un participante). El proceso será el siguiente:

-Partiremos de una lista posicional de resultados vacía.
-Para cada participante:
-elegimos aleatoriamente a quién va a otorgar cada puntuación.
-Cuando un participante reciba puntos, si no estaba en la lista posicional se
añadirá y debe ubicarse en la posición correspondiente a
su número de puntos

Esto es lo que he hecho pero no consigo hacer aleatoriamente el reparto sin repetir votos y como hacerlo bien

```
participantes=['A','B','C','D']

resultados=[] #aqui saco los resultados

cont=[0]*len(participantes)#contador de puntos para cada participante


for i in participantes:
    voto=input("Selecciona a quien votas")
    puntos=int(input("puntos escogidos"))
    if voto in participantes:
        posicion=participantes.index(voto) #posicion del participante
        cont[posicion]+=puntos #sumo los puntos
 
lista=sum(cont)  
contganador=max(cont)
posgan=cont.index(contganador)
ganador=participantes[posgan]
print(lista  , ganador)
```

Comment: ¿Cada participante vota 6 veces? Es decir, concede a un participante 6 puntos, a otro 5, a otro 4 y así sucesivamente?

Comment: si,sería lo correcto

Comment: sin votarse a si mismo y los votos son al azar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si entendí el planteo, no soy capaz de resolverlo siguiendo tu código, así que lo haré con el mío:

lo primero es importar la biblioteca random para elegir al azar

```
import random

participantes=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

resultados=[] # aqui saco los resultados
total={}      # estarán todos los participantes y su puntaje final
```

Agrego todos los participantes al diccionario con un puntaje de 0

```
for part in participantes:
   total.setdefault(part,0)

for x in participantes:  #para cada participante
   puntos = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  #los puntos a otorgar
   posibles = participantes.copy() #una copia de los participantes para poderla modificar 
   
   for i in range(1,7): # por cada posible voto
```

hay que elegir a quien votar al azar

```
      voto = random.choice(posibles)
```

hay que elegir el puntaje otorgado al azar

```
      puntaje = random.choice(puntos)
```

sumamos a cada participante del diccionario el puntaje parcial

```
      total[voto]+=puntaje
```

esta línea es optativa por si quieren ver quien vota a quien y el puntaje otorgado en mi caso la dejo como comentario

```
      #print(f"El participante {x} vota al participante {voto} con {puntaje} puntos  :")
```

elimino el participante para que ya no pueda ser votado por el mismo participante

```
      posibles.remove(voto)
```

elimino los puntos usados

```
      puntos.remove(puntaje)
```

recorro el diccionario y para cada clave y valor la agrego como tupla a resultados

```
for k,v in total.items():
   resultados.append((k,v))
```

ordeno en base al segundo elemento de la tupla en forma descendente

```
resultados = sorted(resultados,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
```

por último muestro la posición final del participante y su puntaje

```
for pos,par in enumerate(resultados,1):
   print(f"La posición final es {pos} el participante {par[0]} con puntos {par[1]}")
```

se puede resumir con comprensión de listas y otras funciones, pero me parece así más fácil de entender.

@sergiof90 fijate si cumple los objetivos y sino vuelve a preguntar aclarando los errores que pude cometer.

Modificación para que use solamente listas, sin explicación, es lo mismo omitiendo diccionarios y tuplas

```
import random

participantes=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

resultados=[] # aqui saco los resultadoss

for part in participantes:
   resultados.append([part,0])

for x in participantes:  #para cada participante
   puntos = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  #los puntos a otorgar
   posibles = participantes.copy() #una copia de los participantes para poderla modificar 
   posibles.remove(x)
   for i in range(1,7): # por cada posible voto
      voto = random.choice(posibles)
      puntaje = random.choice(puntos)
      for z in resultados:
         if z[0] == voto:
            z[1]+=puntaje 
            
      print(f"El participante {x} vota al participante {voto} con {puntaje} puntos  ")
      posibles.remove(voto)

      puntos.remove(puntaje)

resultados = sorted(resultados,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)

for pos,par in enumerate(resultados,1):
   print(f"La posición final es {pos} el participante {par[0]} con puntos {par[1]}")
```

Comment: @BetaM edita mis repuestas todas las veces que quieras eso no me quita la razón

Comment: Tómalo con calma @tincopasan ;), **nunca** dije que no tuvieras razón, solo edite y quite algo que **no** veo que forme parte de tu respuesta, tranquilo

Comment: Muchas gracias,el objetivo era hacerlo con listas pero no lo indiqué, si te fijas se votan a sí mismos en ocasiones como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: en este código una forma sería agregar:  posibles.remove(x ) después de:  posibles = participantes.copy() , creo que teniendo la base sería cuestión de cambiar los diccionarios por listas, apenas pueda lo agrego sino lo hace alguien más.

Comment: muchas gracias compa!